# How to get page HTML before it get changed by Javascript in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to get the page pure html, to make a diff after the scripts evaluations. But I'm finding nothing.

I checked in the Web Page Module API page. http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/

But every event returns me the HTML after being affected by the page scripts, or an empty html structure.

Comment: If you're doing this for your own personal debugging, just use `Ctrl-U` to retrieve the page's original source. Otherwise it gets a little more complicated.

Comment: Sorry. I had no time to test it. I'll do today. But I think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API call for that, but you can easily download the original page source as a separate XHR:

```
var originalSource = page.evaluate(function(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", ""+window.location, false);
    xhr.send();
    return xhr.responseText;
});
```

Though, this will probably not work if the page source depends on the session. A tweaking of request headers might work then. See also [Can I get the original page source (vs current DOM) with phantomjs/casperjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24069722/1816580)