# How do you access the unaltered source of a page via phantomjs

Tags: javascript, curl, phantomjs, diff

Using phantomjs, it's possible to get access to a copy of the modified DOM, post-parsing. Using a cURL call you can get access to the page pre-parsing. In the pre-parsed code, you may find errors which are corrected by a browser.

How do you get access to both the post-rendered changes and the pre-rendered content to make a comparison of the fixes the browser does automatically?

Is the best method to use DIFF on the two files or does phantomjs hold two copies of the content, the original and the modified forms? I can't seem to find the right way to phrase this to get an answer via google and a search here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[phantomjs]+save+unaltered+source didn't turn up any results.

I'd like to avoid a second call to the same page for bandwidth/efficiency reasons.

Comment: Likely not possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069722/can-i-get-the-original-page-source-vs-current-dom-with-phantomjs-casperjs

Comment: I'd read that post, but I thought it was about the JS modifying the DOM.  I am less concerned about the JS modifying and more concerned about whether the browser closes open tags or shortens <meta /> to <meta> for example - I know there's the option to pull down a copy in the browser, but it's a modified copy.  It's still unclear from that post if it's possible or not for this purpose.

Comment: You mean what's on the wire. No, there is no way to get that in PhantomJS, but you can make an ajax request to simply get the page again.

Comment: @ArtjomB.I didn't think about that at all.  Can you simply just request the raw html of the whole page again from that context and save the raw string out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly access the unaltered source (referred to as view-source in other browsers) in PhantomJS.

You could try to read the page from the PhantomJS cache (when run with the [`--disk-cache=true` option](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html)), but there is an easier method. You can simply sent an AJAX request to get the source "on the wire", but then you would need to handle redirect yourself.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    fs = require('fs');

function get(page, url) {
    return page.evaluate(function(url){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, false);
        xhr.send(null);
        return xhr.responseText;
    }, url);
}

var url = 'http://example.com';

page.open(url, function(){
    var co = get(page, url);
    fs.write("original.html", co);
    fs.write("rendered.html", page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

You can already see with this simple script that the two files are different despite not involving JavaScript.

[image]

You might need to run with the `--web-security=false` option. Instead of passing the `url` into the `get()` function, you may directly access `page.url`:

```
function get(page, url) {
    url = url || page.url;
    return page.evaluate(function(url){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, false);
        xhr.send(null);
        return xhr.responseText;
    }, url);
}
```

Comment: Hi Artjom B, that looks like exactly what I need.  For me, a perfect answer.